# How can I autofill specific fields in a webview on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I'm looking to create an Android app (Kotlin) that, when a button is clicked, navigates to a webpage, autofills predefined values, and performs a login action.

I tried to do it as below but it was not successful:

```
val webView = binding.webView
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
val loginPage = "http://example.com/login"
webView.loadUrl(loginPage)

val username = "4000000000"
val password = "1234567890"

binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener {
    val jsCode = """
    document.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value = "$username";
    document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value = "$password";
    document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click();
    """.trimIndent()

    webView.evaluateJavascript(jsCode, null)
```

I'm receptive to different ways for logging into a specific site with a button click.